# [aws-eks]How to give names to ec2 instances created with cluster.add_nodegroup_capacity

Tags: python, aws-cdk, amazon-eks

I am using aws-cdk and aws-eks, while creating the cluster and giving it a nodegroup capacity **I cant find a way to provide names for the ec2 instances**, they are empty in the AWS ec2 console.

This is the code I am using:

```
cluster = aws_eks.Cluster(self, "MetricsCluster",
                                  cluster_name=f"metrics-cluster-{stage}",
                                  version=aws_eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_17,
                                  default_capacity=0)

cluster.add_nodegroup_capacity("MetricsNodes",
                                nodegroup_name=f"eks-nodes-{stage}",
                                instance_type=aws_ec2.InstanceType("t3a.large"),
                                desired_size=2,
                                min_size=1,
                                max_size=3)
```

I also tried providing it with tags:

```
tags={"Key": "Name","Value": f"metrics-nodes-{stage}"}
```

But it didn't help.

Is there another option to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the tag function from aws_cdk.core to tag all resource associated to the construct.

```
    core.Tag.add(cluster, key='Name', value='eks-cluster')
    core.Tag.add(cluster, key='env', value='dev')
    core.Tag.add(cluster, key='cfn.single-env.stack', value='eks-stack')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it with CDK version 2.88.0 in this way with `tags` and `tolerations` as an additional example:

```
        nodegroup = cluster.add_nodegroup_capacity(
            'Nodegroup',
            instance_types=[ec2.InstanceType('t3.medium')],
            desired_size=2,
            min_size=2,
            max_size=4,
            ami_type=eks.NodegroupAmiType.AL2_X86_64,
            tags={
                'Name': f'eks-1-26-{stage}-default-node',
                'environment': f'{stage}',
                'component': 'devops'                
            },
            taints=[
                {
                    'key': 'CriticalAddonsOnly',
                    'value': 'true',
                    'effect': eks.TaintEffect.NO_SCHEDULE
                },
                {
                    'key': 'CriticalAddonsOnly',
                    'value': 'true',
                    'effect': eks.TaintEffect.NO_EXECUTE
                }
             ]
         )
```

Doc: [aws_cdk.aws_eks.Cluster.add_nodegroup_capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_eks/Cluster.html#aws_cdk.aws_eks.Cluster.add_nodegroup_capacity)